# xargs (or something else) without space before parameter

Tags: linux, git, xargs, git-squash

I would like to execute something like this (git squash):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

extracting the 3 from `git log`:

```
git log | blabla | xargs git rebase -i HEAD~
```

This does not work because xargs inserts a space after `HEAD~`.

The problem is that I want to alias this command, so I cannot just use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~`git log | blabla`
```

because the number would be evaluated just when I define the alias.

I don't have to use `xargs`, I just need an alias (preferably not a function).

Comment: the whole command is this: git log | grep Author | head | awk '{print $2}' | sed '/[^gismo]/q' | head -n -1 | wc -l | xargs -I% git rebase -i HEAD~%

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `-I` option of `xargs`:

```
git log | blabla | xargs -I% git rebase -i HEAD~%
```

Comment: For more info: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git log | blabla | xargs -i bash -c 'git rebase -i HEAD~{}'
```

Comment: the reason of 'bash -c' in this answer is explained here, I think you need it if the first command takes a while to execute: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65212/why-doesnt-this-xargs-command-work